# How to test restclient using RestTemplate and JUnit?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, junit, resttemplate

I am new to JUNIT and using `RestTemplate` to call my service, I'm getting 200 response for the same. But, I can't test the class using JUnit. Tried different approaches and getting 400 and 404. I want to post the request body (json) and test the status. Please let me know if there is any issue.

```
/**
* Rest client implementation
**/  
public class CreateEmailDelegate implements CDM {
         
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private  String url = "http://example.com/communications/emails";
        
    public ResponseEntity<CDResponse> createEmail(CDMEmailRequest cDRequest) throws UnavailableServiceException, InvalidInputException {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("SR_API_Key", SR_API_KEY);
        httpHeaders.set("consumerIdentification", CONSUMER_IDENTIFICATION);
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);         
        HttpEntity< CDMEmailRequest > cDRequestEntity = new HttpEntity<>( cDRequest, httpHeaders);  
        ResponseEntity< CDResponse > cDResponse = null;
                
        try {
            cDResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, cDRequestEntity, CDResponse.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            throw  e;       
        }
                
        return cDResponse;
    }
}
```

My Test class which return 404 status instead of 200

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class CreateEmailCommunicationDelegateTest {
    
        @Before
        public void setup() {
            httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.set("SR_API_Key", SR_API_KEY);
            httpHeaders.set("consumerIdentification", CONSUMER_IDENTIFICATION);
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            DefaultMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac);
            this.mockMvc = builder.build();
        }
    
    
        public void testResponse() throws Exception, HttpClientErrorException, JsonProcessingException {
            String url = "http://example.com/CommunicationDeliveryManagement-Service-1.0.0/communications/emails";
    
            CDMEmailRequest anObject = new CDMEmailRequest();
            ResultMatcher ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
            ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            String requestJson = ow.writeValueAsString(anObject);
    
            System.out.println(requestJson);
            MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(requestJson);
            this.mockMvc.perform(builder).andExpect(ok).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
        }
    }
```

My Test class using `TestRestTemplate` instead `MockMvc` returns 400

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CreateEmailCommunicationDelegateTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        // rest headers as above
    }

    @Test
    public void testResponse() throws Exception, HttpClientErrorException, JsonProcessingException {

        String url = "http://example.com/CommunicationDeliveryManagement-Service-1.0.0/communications/emails";

        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        HttpEntity<CDMEmailRequest>
                cDEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);

        restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(username, password);

        responseEntity =
                restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, cDEntity,
                        CDResponse.class);

        assertNotNull(responseEntity);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK,
                responseEntity.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. I see you using the Mockito Runner and you tagged the question with mockito as well, but I don`t see any interaction with mockito in the code.

Comment: removed it, thank u

Comment: It is an external service ?

Comment: yes, it is which is rest service

Comment: You can't use MockMvc or TestRestTemplate for Restclients testing see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to implement an integration test instead of an unit test, there is quite difference. `MockMvc` should be used to implement unit tests and `TestRestTemplate` for integration tests. You can't neither use it for testing a Client implementation.

See [Unit and Integration Tests in Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/unit-and-integration-tests-in-spring-boot)

If you are working with Spring Boot you could achieve your goal using another approach see this question [Spring boot testing of a rest client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538025/spring-boot-testing-of-a-rest-client-using-restclienttest) using [@RestClientTest](https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I am trying to do Integration test only (Springboot). I will follow with the example you mentioned and check.

Comment: @susan if the answer helps you to fix you issue please vote it